# How to generate a monthly average of percentages with SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I currently have a column group set that gives me totals grouped by the month. At the bottom of that report I have a percentage rate that is generated by:

Taking the `total` amount of calls with a `status of answered` and dividing them by `all calls` which is then thrown into the `FormatPercent() function`.

I would now like to get a monthly average of those monthly groupings in percent format. Is this possible?

Here is a screenshot of the table:
[image]

The red box is my ColumnGroup and the arrow is where I would like my percentage.

**EDIT**

For example:

```
Calls by Month | <<Expr>> (MONTHS ARE GENERATED FROM A COL GROUP) |Monthly Average    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Answered | <<Expr>> (Sum of Total Answered by Month)        |<<Expr>> TA/#Months|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Calls    | <<Expr>> (Sum of Total Calls by Month)           |<<Expr>> TC/#Months|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Answered     | <<Expr>> (Total Answered/Total Calls by Month)   |<<Expr>> See Below |
```

`See Below <Expr>>: The sum of each previous months data/# of Months` - This is what I am trying to accomplish

Here is some sample data:

```
Calls by Month | January | February | March | Monthly Average |
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total Answered |   10    |    60    |   5   |        25       |
---------------------------------------------------------------
Total Calls    |   50    |    100   |   10  |        53.33    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
% Answered     |   20%   |    60%   |   50% |        43.3%    |  <---I have been unable
                                                                     to achieve this %
```

**EDIT 2**

Would anyone know of the possibility of creating a custom function to help me accomplish this?

**EDIT 3**

I have found this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a9320181-9c25-45f6-9ee5-7466bbfe8d38/ssrs-2008-r2-add-moving-average-to-column-group?forum=sqlreportingservices

And the answer seems pretty close to what I am looking for, I just really don't understand it enough to figure out what is happening behind the scenes to make it work for me. Would anyone be able to help?

**Edit 4**

Would it be possible to use the `RunningValue` function somehow?

Hope this helps with the confusion.

Comment: Need some input data  and expected result .

Comment: @CoderofCode - Please see my edit above. I hope this helps! Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the groupings on the table?

Comment: @SQLDiver - Thanks for the reply. What specifically would you like screenshot?

Comment: The table with the groupings

Comment: @SQLDiver - how this helps. Please let me know what else you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out myself. I little bit of smoke and mirrors, but I got the result I needed. Here is what I did:

1. Created a `RowGroup` below the data I was trying to get the monthly average of.
2. Used the `RunningValue` function like this: `RunningValue(Total Answered/Total Calls Fields,Avg,"NameOfRowGroupCreated")`
3. Set that Textbox as the monthly average and wrap it in a `FormatPercent` function like this: `=FormatPercent(ReportItems!Textbox219.Value,1)`
4. Hide your `RowGroup`